# Java: Ask user if they want to play again?

Tags: java

I'm making a rock paper scissors game and once computer or user has one best 2/3 then it should prompt if they want to play the game again. if "Yes" then the program restarts and if "no" then system.exit I guess.

How should I go about this?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int gameCount = 0;
    int computerWins = 0;
    int playerWins = 0;
    int rock, paper, scissors;
    rock = 1;
    paper = 2;
    scissors = 3;
    int playerChoice = 0;
    int computerChoice;

    System.out.println("Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors! Best 2 out of 3!");

    //While the game count is less than 3, the loop will repeat
    while (gameCount < 3) {
        computerChoice = r.nextInt(3) + 1;
        System.out.println("Enter \"Rock\", \"Paper\", or \"Scissors\"");
        String USER_Input = userInput.next();
        if (USER_Input.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock")) {
            playerChoice = 1;
        }
        if (USER_Input.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper")) {
            playerChoice = 2;
        }
        if (USER_Input.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors")) {
            playerChoice = 3;
        }
        //If player enters anything besides rock, paper, or scissors
        if (playerChoice <= 0 || playerChoice > 3) {
            System.out.println("That wasn't an option");
            computerWins++;
            gameCount++;
            System.out.println("Not a valid input! Computer Wins!\n" +
                    "Player has won " +playerWins + " times and the computer " +
                    "has won " + computerWins + " times");

            //The game goes on, and the winners are added up!
        } else if (playerChoice == 1 && computerChoice == 2) {
            computerWins++;
            gameCount++;
            System.out.println("Rock v Paper! Computer Wins!\n" +
                    "Player has won " + playerWins + " times and the computer " +
                    "has won " + computerWins + " times");
        } else if (playerChoice == 2 && computerChoice == 1) {
            playerWins++;
            gameCount++;
            System.out.println("Paper v Rock! Player Wins!\n" +
                    "Player has won " + playerWins + " times and the computer " +
                    "has won " + computerWins + " times");
        } else if (playerChoice == 2 && computerChoice == 3) {
            computerWins++;
            gameCount++;
            System.out.println("Paper v Scissors! Computer Wins!\n" +
                    "Player has won " + playerWins + " times and the computer " +
                    "has won " + computerWins + " times");
        } else if (playerChoice == 3 && computerChoice == 2) {
            playerWins++;
            gameCount++;
            System.out.println("Scissors v Paper! Player Wins!\n" +
                    "Player has won " + playerWins + " times and the computer " +
                    "has won " + computerWins + " times");
        } else if (playerChoice == 3 && computerChoice == 1) {
            computerWins++;
            gameCount++;
            System.out.println("Scissors v Rock! Computer Wins!\n" +
                    "Player has won " + playerWins + " times and the computer " +
                    "has won " + computerWins + " times");
        } else if (playerChoice == 1 && computerChoice == 3) {
            playerWins++;
            gameCount++;
            System.out.println("Rock v Scissors! Player Wins!\n" +
                    "Player has won " + playerWins + " times and the computer " +
                    "has won " + computerWins + " times");
        } else if (playerChoice == 1 && computerChoice == 1) {
            gameCount++;
            System.out.println("Rock v Rock! Tie!\n" +
                    "Player has won " + playerWins + " times and the computer " +
                    "has won " + computerWins + " times");
        } else if (playerChoice == 2 && computerChoice == 2) {
            gameCount++;
            System.out.println("Paper v Paper! Tie!\n" +
                    "Player has won " + playerWins + " times and the computer " +
                    "has won " + computerWins + " times");
        } else if (playerChoice == 3 && computerChoice == 3) {
            gameCount++;
            System.out.println("Paper v Paper! Tie!\n" +
                    "Player has won " + playerWins + " times and the computer " +
                    "has won " + computerWins + " times");
        }

        //Check if game count reaches max games then chooses a winner
        if (gameCount == 3 && computerWins > playerWins || computerWins == 2) {
            System.out.println("The Computer Wins!");
            break;
        } else if (gameCount == 3 && computerWins < playerWins || playerWins ==2) {
            System.out.println("The Player Wins!");
        } else if (gameCount == 3 && computerWins == playerWins) {
            System.out.println("The game is a tie!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check for the user input and if it is a "yes" or something then call the method main()

Comment: `"That wasn't an option" => computerWins++` you get my +1

Comment: Haha thanks fr_andres ;) the computer always wins!
@ivan I didn't know you could call the main method again, that's interesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your whole logic is within the main()-method. I suggest you move the while{}-part into a new method like play().

In your main() implement a new while() with prompting your message and reading the input from the keyboard:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput = "";
        do {
            play();
            System.out.print("Do you want to play again ([Y] / n)? ");
            userInput = inputScanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(userInput);
        } while (userInput.equals("Y") || userInput.equals(""));
}
```

HTH, SiS

Comment: I'm sorry I have never made another method outside the main method yet. If I put this before my other code won't it ask the user to play again before anything else happens to get you to that point? I'm just trying to figure out how to implement this into my code to get the exact fit

Comment: Hi Christopher. No it won't as the main() method is the program entry point. Line 1 and 2 in the main are "just variable declaration". Line 3 is the begin of of your requested "play again"-Loop.  Then in line 4 with "play()" your new function private static void play() { your whole loop form your initial post } is executed. At this point no prompting happened. The first prompt comes with line 5 and 6 which are after the first call of play();

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to place the game in another while loop(that envelops that of the gameCount) and within the while loop create a switch statement for a variable lets say `gameContinue`. At the end of the game the user would receive a prompt saying whether to continue or not. Based on their answer you change the value of the variable `gameContinue` and there you go.